# Varnish cache - How to purge/delete cache only for Home page

Tags: drupal, caching, drupal-7, varnish, varnish-vcl

I'm using Drupal 7 latest dev version.

I have installed Varnish and Expire modules and setup them. They are working very well but I have one problem regarding deleting cache from varnish.

The problem is how to **delete** varnish cache only for **index(home)** page and not to delete cache for other pages. I look at he varnish log and I found that whole varnish cache is deleted every time Drupal executes command

```
 ban req.http.host ~ www.cdm.me && req.url ~ "/"
```

This command is executed by varnish module or expire module and it means delete cache of home(index) page. But as I see it is deleting all cached pages in varnish.

**How to fix this? How can I delete only cache for home page?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should invoke other command from Drupal:

```
ban req.http.host ~ www.cdm.me && req.url ~ "^/$"
```

Cache invalidated for whole site, because regexp "/" matches all URLs

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
ban req.http.host == www.cdm.me && ban req.url == "/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this Drupal Purge module do it for you? https://drupal.org/project/purge

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Varnish HTTP Accelerator Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/varnish) module, which provides a very useful function varnish_purge().

Use the function to clear the varnish cache.